# How to display elements data stored in a javascript array as list elements in the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-lists

I am a newbie at web development. I am trying to display data that is being stored in javascript array, inside an unordered list  as list elements.
I have tried looping through the elements in the array and display them one at a time using for loops but its not working

```js
let linksArray = [] // array to store link leads while browsing
let inputEl = document.getElementById("input-el") // to get a hold on the input element from the dom
let displayEl = document.getElementById("display_link-el")

//function to save links inputs into linksArray
function save(params) {
  linksArray.push(inputEl.value)
  console.log(linksArray);
  localStorage.setItem("mylinks", JSON.stringify(linksArray))
  inputEl.value = ""
  displayEl.textContent = linksArray
}

//function to conver linksArray to a list element in the DOM
function convetToListli(linksArray) {
  for (let i = 0; i < linksArray.length; i++) {
    let links = "<li>"
    linksArray[i]
    " </li>"

  }

}
```

```html
<input id="input-el" title="lead" placeholder="input weblink" type="text">
<button id="input-btn" onclick="save()">SAVE </button>
<button id="del-btn" ondblclick="delLeads()">DELETE</button>
<div>
  <div>
    <ul id="display_link-el"></ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul id="log_link-el"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "*but its not working*" - how is it "not working"? What goes wrong? What did you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Are there any errors reported in the console?

Comment: You only have one element in the array so is an array the right solution? What does `params` do?

Answer (score 0):

You should learn basic DOM manipulations. Here's one possible solution for your question

```js
const list = document.querySelector('.list');

const links = ['link 1', 'link 2', 'link 3'];

links.forEach(link => {
  let item = document.createElement('li');
  item.textContent = link;
  list.appendChild(item)
})
```

```html
<ul class="list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added small correction to your script

```
function save(params) {
  linksArray.push(inputEl.value)
  console.log(linksArray);
  inputEl.value=""
  displayEl.innerHTML = convetToListli(linksArray)
}

//function to conver linksArray to a list element in the DOM
function convetToListli(linksArray) {
var links = ""
  for (let i = 0; i < linksArray.length; i++) {
    links= links + "<li>"+linksArray[i]+" </li>"  
  }
  return links
  
}
```

This is just for example purchase

NOTE: Make sure to filter the input field while using innerHTML because it will leads to XSS